# Controlling verbosity of make

Tags: makefile, verbosity

I'm using a makefile to compile a program made of many `.c` files, and any time `make` is invoked it only compiles those files modified after the last run (nothing special until here).

To avoid cluttering my screen, I prepend `@` at the beginning of each `$(CC)` call, and before it I print a customized `echo` message. For example:

```
%.o: %.c $(h1) $(h3) %.h
    @echo -e "\tCompiling <" $< 
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(libDir)$@$(MATHOPTS)
```

My question is: how can I control the verbosity of `make` in a more "dynamic way", in order to be able to:

1. **Normal behaviour**: only a customized message is printed for every makefile rule executed.
2. **Verbose behaviour**: print the command actually executed by every makefile rule (as if the `@` wasn't used at all).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd do it the way automake does:

```
V = 0
ACTUAL_CC := $(CC)
CC_0 = @echo "Compiling $<..."; $(ACTUAL_CC)
CC_1 = $(ACTUAL_CC)
CC = $(CC_$(V))

%.o: %.c $(h1) $(h3) %.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(libDir)$@$(MATHOPTS)
```

If you need to execute other commands in your rules, I like the following snippet. Write `$(AT)` instead of `@` and it will be silent when `V=0` but printed when `V=1`.

```
AT_0 := @
AT_1 := 
AT = $(AT_$(V))
```

Comment: In your first part I suppose one also need to override `CC = $(CC_$(V))`.

Comment: Yes. It's absence was a brain fart that I'll fix now. I should also point out that recursive variable expansion is widely implemented but not currently in POSIX (but that will change in a future revision).

Comment: Great solution @JackKelly. The one creating the `AT` variable is simple and effective!.

Comment: Your code does not work for me.  I get https://gist.github.com/JasonGross/7103651.

Comment: I had to do `CC := $(CC_$(V))` (note the colon) to stop `make` from complaining that 'Recursive variable CC references itself'.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: This is not working for me either. I get "Makefile:12: *** Recursive variable 'CC' references itself (eventually).  Stop." When using exactly the first solution. Im using "GNU Make 4.0"

Comment: @everlof, edited to fix that error, seems to work fine now.

Comment: Why not just use the `.SILENT:` special target?  It's fully generic (don't need to redefine all the the program variables like `CC`, `CXX`, `LD`, `AR`, etc.).  A more complete discussion with examples is available at: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/  The `.SILENT` target is part of POSIX so it should work everywhere, very easily.  The only difference from this is it prints the output of the `echo` (but not the `echo` command itself) even in verbose mode.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution (one which I like because it's flexible)

```
ifeq ("$(BUILD_VERBOSE)","1")
Q :=
vecho = @echo
else
Q := @
vecho = @true
endif

%.o: %.c
    $(vecho) "-> Compiling $@"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You can skip the vecho stuff, but it does come in handy at times.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using "@gcc" to compile, you can omit that "@" and pass the "-s" option to your make command instead. (Leave "@echo" as it is.) Then "make -s" would be your brief make command, and "make" would be verbose.

> The ‘-s’ or ‘--silent’ flag to make prevents all echoing, as if all recipes started with ‘@’.

[From the GNU Make manual pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing)

(The other answers better answer your question, but this approach deserves a mention.)

Answer (score 4):

I would create a function which takes a command to execute and decides whether to echo it.

```
# 'cmd' takes two arguments:
#   1. The actual command to execute.
#   2. Optional message to print instead of echoing the command
#      if executing without 'V' flag.
ifdef V
cmd = $1
else
cmd = @$(if $(value 2),echo -e "$2";)$1
endif

%.o: %.c $(h1) $(h3) %.h
    $(call cmd, \
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(libDir)$@$(MATHOPTS), \
        Compiling $<)
```

Then the result of plain `make` invocation will be something like:

```
Compiling foo.c
```

Whereas `make V=1` will give:

```
gcc -Wall -c foo.c -o foo.o ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Eldar! Your suggestion is very good, but redefining the "@" as proposed by Jack is simpler. BTW, I didn't know at all that you could define a function that way.

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment on the `AT = $(AT_$(V))` suggestion, note that Automake does provide a standard macro that does the same thing as `AT`, which is called `AM_V_at`.

You will also find that it has another very useful `AM_V_GEN` variable, that resolves either to nothing or to `@echo "  GEN   " $@;`, depending on the verbosity.

This allows you to code something like this:

```
grldr.mbr: mbrstart
    $(AM_V_GEN)
    $(AM_V_at)-rm -f grldr.mbr
    $(AM_V_at)cat mbrstart > grldr.mbr
```

The output of which will be either (verbosity disabled):

```
  GEN    grldr.mbr
```

or (verbosity enabled):

```
rm -f grldr.mbr
cat mbrstart > grldr.mbr
```

Pretty convenient, and this removes the need to define your own macros.