# Recursive makefile for c++ source

Tags: c++, makefile

I've been struggling with makefiles for a while now, since I don't really get how they work...

My directory structure is as followed:

```
--bin/
--build/
--includes/
--src/
----classes/
------somefiles.hpp
------somefiles.cpp
----states/
------somestates.hpp
----main.cpp
----few-other-files.cpp
--Makefile
--.gitignore
```

Which worked fine with my makefile, until I started adding those subdirs, `classes` and `states`

I can't seem to find how to include those subdirs in my makefile which is:

```
CC := g++
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/game

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -g -Wall
LIB := -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-system -lsfml-window
INC := -I includes -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking..."
    @echo "$(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning..."
    @echo "$(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
```

Problem: `Fatal error: can't create build/classes/stateManager.o: No such file or directory`

Normally, the problem is that it can't build the directory. But I thought the `mkdir -p` would solve that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you only do `mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)` which is equal to `mkdir -p build`. The subdirectories (like `classes`) are not created. You might be interested in the `dir` function (see e.g. [this `make` file-function manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions)).

Comment: Also a little nitpicking on the term "recursive makefile". A recursive makefile is a makefile that invokes itself, usually in subdirectories. Your makefile is *not* recursive.

Comment: Which ended up as: `@mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)`, If I'm correct?

Comment: You may want to have a look at `VPATH` and `vpath`.

Comment: Or `@mkdir -p $(dir $@)`

Comment: With which a new problem arises. The object files are successfully made and put in the `build` directory. But, the linker throws out an `undefined reference to main`. This usually is because of a missing `-c` flag, but it is not in this case.

Comment: With which a new question arises, hopefully showing the actual specific error and the linker command that reproduces it.

Comment: BTW, most of your `@echo` statements could be removed, since running make with debugging enabled will print the expanded command anyway. That saves having to keep two copies of the same rule in sync.

Comment: I prefer just running `make` and getting to choose what I echo and what not.

Comment: If you remove the `@` at the front of the line (along with the echo), it will echo the exact command it's running, which I believe is your intent..  Alternatively you could use something like [this]<https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609811/7673414>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
```

with

```
mkdir -p $(@:D)
```

---

Another way is to let `make` treat directories as targets and have them automatically created for you, so that you do not have to clutter your recipes with `mkdir -p` invocations:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
# Make the object file depend on its directory using order-only dependency.
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT) | $$(dir $$@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# Let make create the directories for your targets.
%/:
    mkdir -p $@

# Do not remove the directories because they are "intermediate" targets.
.PRECIOUS : %/
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the explanation.